# Using Multiple Raster Intermediate Inputs in Raster Calculator within QGIS Process Modeler

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

I am stringing together a series of raster calculations in the QGIS process modeler in order to calculate a surface temperature dataset from Landsat and weather data.

When I use the output from multiple prior algorithms in the model as the input for a raster calculation, the result is a blank grid (-1.79769e+308 to 1.79769e+308). Calculations performed with input parameter bands work as expected.

This issues appears to have been addressed [in this QGIS bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19302).

However I've updated my install and the problem persists. Can anyone advise on this? I'd rather not split my model into several smaller models.

Comment: Are you using the Qgis raster calculator or the gdal one? I have found in the graphical modeler the gdal one is more straight forward to link.

Comment: Thank you, I was using the QGIS raster calculator -- switching to gdal fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad that worked- I created an answer for future frustrated users. If you could accept it that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 raster calculators that you can use in the graphical modeler: Native Qgis, Saga, and GDAL.  I have found the gdal one to work better than the native Qgis one in the modeler because it is set up to define your inputs as raster1 = A and raster2 = B first and then use them in your equation. For example A+B. I have not used the SAGA one.